# Databricks - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException

Tags: classpath, databricks, azure-databricks, apache-hudi

We can't figure out the following issue: we are trying to use Apache Hudi to save data to the storage. The problem is when we upload a fat jar which includes the org.json package in dependencies, the `df.save()`  application is failing on

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeCreateTable(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10847)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genResolvedParseTree(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.CalcitePlanner.analyzeInternal(CalcitePlanner.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:308)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1049)
    at org.apache.hudi.hive.HoodieHiveClient.updateHiveSQLs(HoodieHiveClient.java:384)
    at org.apache.hudi.hive.HoodieHiveClient.updateHiveSQLUsingHiveDriver(HoodieHiveClient.java:367)
    at org.apache.hudi.hive.HoodieHiveClient.updateHiveSQL(HoodieHiveClient.java:357)
    at org.apache.hudi.hive.HoodieHiveClient.createTable(HoodieHiveClient.java:262)
    at org.apache.hudi.hive.HiveSyncTool.syncSchema(HiveSyncTool.java:176)
    at org.apache.hudi.hive.HiveSyncTool.syncHoodieTable(HiveSyncTool.java:130)
    at org.apache.hudi.hive.HiveSyncTool.syncHoodieTable(HiveSyncTool.java:94)
    at org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$.org$apache$hudi$HoodieSparkSqlWriter$$syncHive(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:321)
    at org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$$anonfun$metaSync$2.apply(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:363)
    at org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$$anonfun$metaSync$2.apply(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:359)
```

Even if I go to the cluster libraries and explicitly add [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20090211) dependency it still fails on save. On the other hand, when I just create `new JSONException("hello")` in my notebook everything seem to work fine. What could cause this behaviour? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was with different classpath between metastore service and spark process, because they run in separated JVM's. The problem was fixed in an init script that downloads the jar to the classpath folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the jar is not making it's way to the executor nodes, try `addJar` (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#addJar-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 0):

What version of Hudi are you using? There is a problem with JSON in version 0.6.0 and there is an [opened issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HUDI-1117). I suggest you to use version 0.5.2 by now.